# Replacing data in column with mean value of corresponding bin?

Tags: python, pandas

I make bins out of my column using pandas' `pd.qcut()`. I would like to, then apply smoothing by corresponding bin's mean value.

I generate my bins with something like

```py
pd.qcut(col, 3)
```

For example,
Given the column values `[4, 8, 15, 21, 21, 24, 25, 28, 34]`
and the generated bins

```
Bin1 [4, 15]: 4, 8, 15
Bin2 [21, 24]: 21, 21, 24
Bin3 [25, 34]: 25, 28, 34
```

I would like to replace the values with the following means

```
Mean of Bin1 (4, 8, 15) = 9
Mean of Bin2 (21, 21, 24) = 22
Mean of Bin3 (25, 28, 34) = 29
```

Therefore:

```
Bin1: 9, 9, 9
Bin2: 22, 22, 22
Bin3: 29, 29, 29
```

making the final dataset: `[9, 9, 9, 22, 22, 22, 29, 29, 29]`

How can one also add a column with closest bin boundaries?

```
Bin1: 4, 4, 15
Bin2: 21, 21, 24
Bin3: 25, 25, 34
```

making the final dataset: `[4, 4, 15, 21, 21, 24, 25, 25, 34]`

very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599429/binning-and-naming-new-columns-with-mean-of-binned-columns) which is for R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly as you laid out.  Using this technique to get [nearest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[4, 8, 15, 21, 21, 24, 25, 28, 34]})

df2 = df.assign(bin=pd.qcut(df.col, 3),
         colbmean=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby("bin").transform("mean"),
         colbin=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: min([r.bin.left,r.bin.right], key=lambda x: abs(x-r.col)), axis=1))
```

|  | col | bin | colbmean | colbin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | (3.999, 19.0] | 9 | 3.999 |
| 1 | 8 | (3.999, 19.0] | 9 | 3.999 |
| 2 | 15 | (3.999, 19.0] | 9 | 19 |
| 3 | 21 | (19.0, 24.333] | 22 | 19 |
| 4 | 21 | (19.0, 24.333] | 22 | 19 |
| 5 | 24 | (19.0, 24.333] | 22 | 24.333 |
| 6 | 25 | (24.333, 34.0] | 29 | 24.333 |
| 7 | 28 | (24.333, 34.0] | 29 | 24.333 |
| 8 | 34 | (24.333, 34.0] | 29 | 34 |

Comment: Any way to achieve this without adding additional columns? I intend to replace the value in column. If not, I am fine with adding and dropping the column instead.

Comment: with both you can change the `assign()` to go straight to the column you want (overwrite).  **bin** in mean could be done the the `groupby()` in the nearest,  I don't see a practical way of doing it without creating the **bin** column then. deleting it

Comment: One final question, What if my column name has a space in it? How would the syntax for assign go?

Comment: just switch to longer hand version `df["my col"]` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You'll find below the solution I came up with to answer your problem.
There is still a limitation, `pandas.qcut` does not return closed intervals, for this matter the results are not exactly the one you described.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [4, 8, 15, 21, 21, 24, 25, 28, 34]})

df['bin'] = pd.qcut(df['value'], 3)
df = df.join(df.groupby('bin')['value'].mean(), on='bin', rsuffix='_average_in_bin')

df['bin_left'] = df['bin'].apply(lambda x: x.left)
df['bin_right'] = df['bin'].apply(lambda x: x.right)
df['nearest_boundary'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['bin_left'] if abs(x['value'] - x['bin_left']) < abs(x['value'] - x['bin_right']) else x['bin_right'], axis=1)
```